# Continuation of the Annotated Pratchett File

Tags: terry-pratchett, discworld

For less recent discworld books, I found the [Annotated Pratchett File](http://www.lspace.org/books/apf/) a very good source of references to popular culture. However, the site appears to have stopped being maintained around the time "Going Postal" was released.

Is there any site with a similar list of hidden allusions to popular culture that also features the most recent works of Terry Pratchett?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think most of the energy that went into maintaining the Annotated Pratchett is now going into maintaining the [LSpace Wiki](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Main_Page), which is a wiki about all things Pratchettian.

Updated versions of The Annotated Pratchett appear to be referenced from the [Annotations page](http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Annotations) (Thanks @b_jonas)